# Linear voltage reducer

Tags: voltage, analog, dc-dc-converter, linear

[image: schematic]

My question is in reference to the circuit above. (An EE non-graded assignment.)

What is the purpose of R1 in this circuit? My feeling is it's providing bias and/or feedback to act as a current limit to the transistors (MJ2955) but I'm struggling to say exactly how or why.

Any better insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A hint. Think about if the resistor was not there and predict the output voltage.

Comment: Do you mean the voltage divider of R1 (2k2) , 1k1 and 1k provide initial bias of MPSA42 which then allows the bias current of the darlington transistors? So if R1 was not there there would be no output? So its like an "enable" resistor.

Comment: c'mon don't leave me hangin :)

Comment: Gotta sleep sometime. Yes you're on the right track..

Comment: So once current is flowing through to a load and say the load increases, and keeps increasing. Does R1 have the effect of becoming "invisible" and apparently "high resistance" shutting down the output? Because the current wants to go through the lower resistance path of the darlington? But even after writing that I dont really agree with it. Which is why I am a little confused by this duplicitous resistor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally speaking I think R1 is to prevent the voltage regulator from oscillating its little head off.

The output transistor(s) has considerable gain due to its configuration of collector feeding the real output - a lot of voltage regulators feed their output with an NPN emitter - these are easy to design and are more-or-less predictably stable but, they won't work well when Vin is close to Vout i.e. they are not low drop-out regulators. Typical example is the 78xx series - they need input to be about 2V greater than Vout to work properly.

The one in your circuit uses a PNP transistor and this will tolerate Vin getting quite close to Vout before the regulation fails. Probably to within 0.5V - this puts it in the class of an LDO regulator (low drop-out).

So, the PNP has quite high gain (voltage fluctuations on base produce much larger fluctations on the collector. This transistor(s) are fed from an emitter follower (no added voltage gain) and that transistor is fed from an NPN which also has considerable voltage gain - it looks like it's a common base circuit - the base receives a bias from the output voltage via the potential divider - it looks like a 1k1 and a 1k but the diagram has seen better days - this, assuming I'm correct, will put about 6V on the base when the circuit is regulating.

Note also, there is a start up circuit (via the 1N4148 diode feeding the base) - this puts "some" voltage on the base to turn it on whilst the circuit settles down to proper regulation. That start-up voltage is "replaced" by the 1k1 and 1k voltage once output has risen sufficiently. The emitter of this transistor is where the feedback control happens. If the output rises a little too high - the emitter also rises and stops conduction of this transistor thus causing the output transistors to start to switch off.

Like I said earlier there is a lot of loop-gain and this gain is dependant on the undisclosed output load. This is because the series pass transistor(s) feed that load via their collectors. This means the loop gain may cause instability on light loads and go into a situation where the output rockets between minimum and maximum voltage - max voltage could indeed be as high as the input voltage and this would be serious a problem.

In summary, I think R1 is intended to stabilize the output on light loads (maximum loop gain) - the output transistor(s) can turn off fully but there will still be a small feed of current to the output which "dampens" down rogue and extreme changes in those transistors.

That's how I see it anyway. I can't see that R1 offers any other function.

Comment: Thanks that explanation really helped, but the Zener still is the reference that determines what the Vout will be once the circuit stabilizes?

Comment: the zener and the two diodes in series determine the point at which the circuit regulates AND the 6 ish volts on the base from the 1k1 and 1k resistor. 6 + 6.2 + 1.4 = 13.6 give or take a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this circuit:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnvTKJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where U1 is an ideal op-amp and D1 is an ideal zener.

The voltages on the op-amp inputs are:

v(+) = \$V_O \cdot \$ \$ R_2 \over (R_1 + R_2)\$ \$ = V_O \cdot k\$

v(-) = 0               (\$V_O \lt V_Z)\$

v(-)   = \$V_O-V_Z \$      (\$V_O \ge V_Z)\$

For the op-amp to be balanced, v(+) = v(-).

I think you can see there are two values of  \$V_O \$ that will satisfy the equality.

We probably want \$V_O =\$ \$ V_Z \over 1-k\$, so we need to prevent the other solution from occurring, so the circuit will *start up* properly.

(It's slightly more complex because the mathematical undesirable solution above is not a stable solution, but the result is similar- the output voltage is not what you want).